# Simulating button click using Win32 API in .NET

Tags: c#

i want to invoke a button in another app but i can't to do it .. after searched i found only one API can do this .. it is SendMessage API but i can't to ues it ...
i develop an windows app that interact with Viber app ( social application like whatsapp ) . i want to pass number in a text box and click on chat logo to write message then sending it ... any help please

here is my sample code

```
namespace ViberMess
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    // Get a handle to an application window.
    [DllImport("USER32.DLL", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName,
        string lpWindowName);

    // Activate an application window.
    [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
    public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Get a handle to the viber application. The window class 
        // and window name were obtained using the Spy++ tool.
        IntPtr calculatorHandle = FindWindow("Qt5QWindowIcon", "Viber +2xxxxxxxxx");

        // Verify that Viber is a running process. 
        if (calculatorHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Viber is not running.");
            return;
        }

        // Make Viber the foreground application and send it  
        // phone number

        SetForegroundWindow(calculatorHandle);
        //Send CTRL+d to open dialled windows
        SendKeys.SendWait("^d");

        //Pass phone number
        SendKeys.SendWait("+2010xxxxxxxx");
        //Here is i want to click on message logo then type text and press Enter
        //My problem how to click on message logo to type text

    }


}
```

Comment: how come you can't use `SendMessage` do you mean you can't or don't know how.. take a look here http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/SamTomato/clicking-a-button-in-another-application/

Comment: yes i don't know how to find chat button

Comment: [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is an entire framework designed to allow you to automate other applications at a much higher semantic level than trying to simulate windows messages. So I'd disagree with there being "only one API". It does have a bit of a learning curve to it but it's designed for this sort of job.

Comment: by using Spy++ i can't to get button id in viber

Comment: The message will be `WM_NOTIFY` with a parameter of `BN_CLICKED` and the control ID.  This is what you should look for in Spy++ and also what you will use with `SendMessage`

Comment: Can you give me an example ... Remember when i drag the scope search of Spy++ on message button ., it's give me the hole dialed window not button

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this problem when trying to hook up an automated GUI tool we have in house.  The problem is due to the way QT emulates windowing.  In order to see window handles in Spy++ (and various Windows API functions) you will need to add an environment variable:

(From Windows 8.1):

1. Go to Control Panel\System and Security\System\Advanced System Settings...
2. On the Advanced tab hit Environment Variables
3. Add a new variable with a name of QT_USE_NATIVE_WINDOWS and value of 1

For user variables you need to restart visual studio

For environment variables you may need to restart the machine

Once all of the above is done you should be able to use Spy++ to get the button handles.

Comment: I sooooo much love you know. I was digging into this problem for ~2 days stright now, and was unable to find a meaningful hint on the web for this. The environment variable hint just saved my day. Thank you!!!

Comment: this solution still works as of now (2020) but the problem is the dialog is rendered all in black